# Left outer join query

Tags: sql-server, outer-join

[image: in Image table - 1 is table with Primery key ID autonumber and DeclarationContentId as FK from another table. There are two column GrantedAmount and DeclaredAmount Identified by the another column AmountType. I want a left outer join query which will return me a for DeclartionContentId with GrantedAmount and DeclaredAmount togather in a single row extepecte output table shown below in the image]

in Image table - 1 is table with Primery key ID autonumber and DeclarationContentId as FK from another table. There are two column GrantedAmount and DeclaredAmount Identified by the another column AmountType. I want a left outer join query which will return me a for DeclartionContentId with GrantedAmount and DeclaredAmount togather in a single row

Comment: Please clarify your question and/or provide an example of the expected result.

Comment: What are your two tables called?  Which columns are in the first table; which columns are in the second table? Why do you want a LOJ query - rather than a regular inner join?

Comment: @Johathan Assume that there is only one column in another table and has only onle column DeclarationContentId as PK. if with inner join its posible to have expected result it ok with me.

Comment: It's not clear whether your second image is the second table or the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Making a some assumptions here

- The two tables are `declarationcontent` and `declarationcontentamount`
- you want the granted amount when the type is 1
- you want the declared amount when the type is 2
- You want zeros instead of null
- Left joins because every type may not be represented for each declarationcontentid

Try this

```
SELECT dc.declarationcontentid, 
       Isnull(ga.grantedamount, 0)  grantedamount, 
       Isnull(dc.declaredamount, 0) declaredamount 
FROM   declarationcontent dc 
       LEFT JOIN declarationcontentamount ga 
         ON dc.declarationcontentid = ga.declarationcontentid 
            AND amounttype = 1 
       LEFT JOIN declarationcontentamount dc 
         ON dc.declarationcontentid = ga.declarationcontentid 
            AND amounttype = 2
```